# Add CSS changes to SCSS File

Tags: css, sass

Say I've built a .CSS file that I compiled from a .SCSS file.

What happens if one of my team members directly edits the .CSS file, and I come along and recompile a change to the .SCSS file?

How do I stop the direct updates to the CSS file being lost?

Comment: You have a quiet word with your team member about how to properly compile Sass. I honestly think the best solution here is prevention rather than cure. Communicate!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.
You must enforce `.css` files to be only written by scss compiler.